# "First" and "Last" from Global Forest Change

Tags: raster, remote-sensing

What are the "first" and "last" rasters provided by the Global Forest Change data set?

Comment: Actually the question was very specific for those who know Global Forest Change. The answer arrived promptly and clear.

Comment: I've upvoted. You still can improve a bit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [their site](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.2.html), they clearly state that:

> **Circa year 2000 Landsat 7 cloud-free image composite (first)**
>
> Reference multispectral imagery from the first available year, typically 2000. If no cloud-free observations were available for year 2000, imagery was taken from the closest year with cloud-free data, within the range 1999–2012.
>
> **Circa year 2014 Landsat cloud-free image composite (last)**
>
> Reference multispectral imagery from the last available year, typically 2014. If
> no cloud-free observations were available for year 2014, imagery was
> taken from the closest year with cloud-free data, within the range
> 2010–2012.

Reference